# Kivy on android: Exception in parser.py create_missing: TypeError: Argument 'name' has incorrect type (expected str, got unicode)

Tags: android, python, kivy, kivy-language

My Kivy app crashes on Android immediately.
I guess this is some Python2/Python3 incompatibility, **but I've got no idea what is the actual reason for this error** (adb logcat output):

```
01-28 14:00:39.421  7457  7492 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Pfadfinder/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 5, in <module>
01-28 14:00:39.421  7457  7492 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Pfadfinder/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/pfadfinder/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 802, in run**strong text**
01-28 14:00:39.421  7457  7492 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Pfadfinder/.buildozer/android/app/pfadfinder/hauptmenue.py", line 152, in build
01-28 14:00:39.422  7457  7492 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Pfadfinder/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/pfadfinder/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 382, in load_string
01-28 14:00:39.422  7457  7492 I python  :    File  "/home/kivy/Pfadfinder/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/pfadfinder/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 496, in _apply_rule
01-28 14:00:39.422  7457  7492 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Pfadfinder/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/pfadfinder/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 281, in create_missing
01-28 14:00:39.423  7457  7492 I python  :  TypeError: Argument 'name' has incorrect type (expected str, got unicode)
```

The app was developed with Python 3.6 on Windows.

On Android, it is running in Python 2.7.2 (Kivy v1.10.0).

Note: I'm German, so the app should work with umlauts ä ö ü.
I am loading the KV file like this:

```
def build(self):
    with io.open(os.path.join(THIS_DIR, "hauptmenue.kv"), encoding='utf-8') as f:
       screen_management = Builder.load_string(f.read())
```

The last line is line 152 mentioned in the stack trace.

The KV file looks like this:

## :kivy 1.1.0

```
ScreenManagement:
    hauptmenue: hauptmenue
    MainMenu:
        id: hauptmenue

<LevelButton>:
    font_size: "40dp"


<MainMenu>:
    name: "hauptmenue"

    level_auswahl: level_auswahl

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.size

        Label:
            text: "Pfadfinder"
            size_hint: (1.0, None)
            font_size: "30dp"
            height: "40dp"

        GridLayout:
            id: level_auswahl
            rows: 6
            cols: 5

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: (1.0, None)
            height: "40dp"
            Button:
                text: "Einstellungen"
                on_release: app.open_settings()
                font_size: "30dp"
            Button:
                text: "Beenden"
                on_release: app.stop()
                font_size: "30dp"

<Einstellungen>:
    name: "einstellungen"
    Settings:
        on_close: app.close_settings()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question.

The error message really wass not very helpful, so I tried to remember what has changed since the last working version.

The method loading the KV file has not changed - this has been like this days before - the reason being that umlauts inside KV texts did not render correctly on Windows.

I had added screen management, an app configuration and a JsonStore, e.g. for the player's nickname. 
Of course I had used umlauts for this name, so I thought these were the culprit.
But this was the wrong trail.

The reason was actually that I had a "name" attribute for the screen(s) in the KV file.

Actually, what helped was to modify the method for loading the KV files in a Python-version dependent way:

```
fname = os.path.join(THIS_DIR, "hauptmenue.kv")
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    with io.open(fname, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        screen_management = Builder.load_string(f.read())
else:
    screen_management = Builder.load_file(fname)
```

Hope this helps others...